# How to return all the values generated by a loop in R

Tags: r

I ran into a bit of a problem using a for loop and I don't know how to exactly remedy it.

First I'll create a similar dataset so the loop and my problem are a bit more clear.
Let's say I have two different data sets:

```
                 DF1                         DF2
|  begin_date  end_date  industry | mean_diff_days  industry  |
   05/12/2013 10/12/2013     A            6            A
   02/11/2011 04/11/2011     B            2            B
   13/10/2018 20/10/2018     A            5            C
   23/06/2020 28/06/2020     C
```

The date variables are in the pattern %d/%m/%Y. My datasets of course cover a lot more observations and variables (; the observations number in the tens of thousands), but the relevant variables for this loop look similar to the 2 datasets shown above. Also important to mention is that the second dataset is derived from the data of the first database.

In this case my loop would look like this:

```
for(i in 1:length(DF1$begin_date)){{

day_diff <- as.Date(as.character(DF1$end_date[i]), format="%d/%m/%Y") - as.Date(as.character(DF1$begin_date[i]), format="%d/%m/%Y")

industry_firm <- DF1$industry[i]

DF1$Timeliness[i] <- as.numeric(mean_diff_days[mean_diff_days$industry == industry_firm,]) - as.numeric(day_diff)
}

return(DF1$Timeliness)

}
```

As can be noticed from the code, I'm trying to create a new variable ("Timeliness") that by taking the difference in days between the begin date and end date for every observation and reducing this difference by the industry mean day difference. This way I have created a measurement for timeliness. Normally I'd finish this off with taking the log of the outcome, to get the relative differences and to avoid skewed data distributions.

The problem that I run in to with this loop is that it assigns one specific value to all the observations. I thought this might've been the outcome of the last run of the loop. Now I have an idea on what the problems might be, but I'm clueless as of this moment on how to salvage them. Does anybody have any idea on how to make sure the loop creates a variable where all outcomes are returned and attached to the right observations.

Also important to mention is that in my actual coding environment, I had already created the variable "Timeliness" in the global environment (and thus the dataset) before running the loop, so I was overwriting the existing values of the variable instead of creating brand new entries.

Many thanks in advance !!

### Data

```r
DF1 <- structure(list(begin_date = c("05/12/2013", "02/11/2011", "13/10/2018", 
"23/06/2020"), end_date = c("10/12/2013", "04/11/2011", "20/10/2018", 
"28/06/2020"), industry = c("A", "B", "A", "C")), problems = structure(list(
    row = 4L, col = "industry", expected = "", actual = "embedded null", 
    file = "literal data"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(begin_date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), end_date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), industry = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))

DF2 <- structure(list(mean_diff_days = c(6, 2, 5), industry = c("A", 
"B", "C")), problems = structure(list(row = 3L, col = "industry", 
    expected = "", actual = "embedded null", file = "literal data"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(mean_diff_days = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), industry = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: You don't use `DF2` in your `for`-loop, but a data.frame/matrix named `mean_diff_days`. Why does your loop use a `return`-function? And finally: how does your expected output based on your given input/example looks like?

Comment: You'd likely want your `i`(s) to be on both sides LeftHandSide[i] <- RightHandSide[i], so you get the advantage of the loop. This would be LHS for `day_diff` and `industry_firm`, RHS for `as.numeric(mean`. Agree with @MartinGal, you don't need return, the for loop returns the last item processed.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my part. It meant to say DF2$mean_diff_days in the second to last line of the loop, where I use the mean from the second dataset to create the Timeliness variable. I used the return function, because otherwise the loop didn't return any value, at least that was the case for me. The expected output would look like a value at the end (so under a new column for the newly created variable) of each observation (each row) of the first dataset, where the value would be =>

Comment: If I remove one of the opening `{` + the `return`-function + one closing `}`inside your loop, and replace `mean_diff_days[mean_diff_days$industry == industry_firm,]` by `DF2[DF2$industry == industry_firm, 1]` I get some values in `DF1$Timeliness`.

Comment: difference in days between end and beginning - the mean difference for the industry relevant to that specific observation.

Comment: Yes, thank you both. I think I have figured it out with the help of both your comments. IT works as it should now !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible `dplyr`-solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

DF1 %>% 
  mutate(
    across(ends_with("_date"), ~as.Date(., format="%d/%m/%Y")),
    day_diff = end_date - begin_date
    ) %>% 
  left_join(DF2, by = "industry") %>% 
  mutate(Timeliness = day_diff - mean_diff_days)
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  begin_date end_date   industry day_diff mean_diff_days Timeliness
  <date>     <date>     <chr>    <drtn>            <dbl> <drtn>    
1 2013-12-05 2013-12-10 A        5 days                6 -1 days   
2 2011-11-02 2011-11-04 B        2 days                2  0 days   
3 2018-10-13 2018-10-20 A        7 days                6  1 days   
4 2020-06-23 2020-06-28 C        5 days                5  0 days
```